# How to store objects in react project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a static website that I’m building.

I have a component built using react. And would like to use different information in them. And also use the component on different pages.

I have the option of making a file and throwing all of my objects in there. But it’s somewhat hard to read.

Any alternatives?

Objects.js

```
Export data1 = [
 {
   Name: Shelly,
   Age:32,
   City:Kansas City
  },
 {
   Name: Michael,
   Age:43,
   City:New York
  },
  ... (hundreds more)
]

Export data2 = [{
 …same structure but needs to be separate from data1
}]
```

Note Page A will use data 1 page b will use data 2

Comment: Hard to read for whom? Either you get data from a file, database or API. If current formatting makes it unreadable for a human being then use code formatters like [prettier](https://prettier.io/).

Comment: Making JSON files and importing from there seems to be the best option IMO, given the data is static.

Alternatively, you can store the data in a redux state. That way it will be easy to access across the application and even if it is static, you can set the values in the reducer which will set it as the initial state. 

(This also helps in case you want to automate some parts in future, you can use the methods from redux itself.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.